# how to create a file with these sqlite instruccions using a .bat script?

Tags: windows, sqlite, batch-file, cmd

I want to create the next sqlite instructions using a .bat script and save them in a temp.txt file. The problem is that some parts of the instructions are variable and depend of a list of files in the current directory.

Example:

In my current directory I have the next files: file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt and some other that I dont care...

So I need to create the next sqlite sentences:

```
insert into table1(fileName) values('THE VARIABLE FILE NAME');
insert into table2(something1) select (idTable1) from table1 where fileName = 'THE VARIABLE FILE NAME';
.import THE VARIABLE FILE NAME table3
```

So the sentences must look like this:

```
insert into table1(fileName) values('file1.txt');
insert into table2(something1) select (idTable1) from table1 where fileName = 'file1.txt';
.import file1.txt table3
insert into table1(fileName) values('file2.txt');
insert into table2(something1) select (idTable1) from table1 where fileName = 'file2.txt';
.import file2.txt table3
insert into table1(fileName) values('file3.txt');
insert into table2(something1) select (idTable1) from table1 where fileName = 'file3.txt';
.import file3.txt table3
```

The file where those instruccions will be saved is named temp.txt

So in the end of myScript.bat I want to execute something like this:

```
sqlite3 < temp.txt
```

And the information in those files will be imported into my database.

And I already know that I can list those files in my cmd with the next instruction:

```
dir f*.txt /b
```

I also know that I can create a empty file like this:

```
echo. 2> temp.txt
```

And that I can write the text that I want into that temp.txt file like this:

```
echo TheseAreMyInstructions >> temp.txt
```

So myScript should start like this

```
@echo off // Wont show more info...
echo. 2> temp.txt // Will create the empty file
```

And I tried something like this

```
FOR %%a IN (dir f*.txt /b) DO echo insert into table1(fileName) values('%%a') >> temp.txt
```

I dont know how to put the other instructions here inside the for

And the results arent what i expected...

The results in my temp.txt file are:

```
insert into table1(fileName) values('dir') // This should not be here!
insert into table1(fileName) values('file1.txt') 
insert into table1(fileName) values('file2.txt') 
insert into table1(fileName) values('file3.txt') 
insert into table1(fileName) values('/b') // This should not be here!
```

Please help me I really have to do this...

Thanks for Your help! ;)

Comment: Why are you trying to put the file names `dir` and `/b` into the file list?

Comment: I don't need that information in my temp.txt file... I just don't know how to make those things disappear. As I said, the results aren't what i expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute commands for a set of files, just specify the file pattern:

```cmd
for %%a in (f*.txt) do (
    echo ...%%a >> sql.txt
    echo %%a... >> sql.txt
)
```

Comment: It worked but I had to put ^ before all the parenthesis. I didnt know that... Also that i was using wrong the for loop... Thanks my friends. This is what i did:

`@echo off
echo. 2> temp.txt
for %%a in (f*.txt) do (
 echo insert into table1^(fileName^) values^('%%a'^) >> temp.txt
 echo insert into table2^(something1^) select^(idTable1^) from table1 where fileName = '%%a' >> temp.txt
 echo .import %%a table3 >> temp.txt
)`